# perl firefox add-on

Tags: perl, firefox, firefox-addon

is it possible to write firefox addon with perl and if yes could some one point to some articles materials about this subject ?

Comment: Found this in Mozilla Mail archives: [firefox extension calling perl script](http://www.mail-archive.com/mozilla-xpcom@mozilla.org/msg05537.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how feasible building a Firefox addon in Perl is, but here are a few links that might get you started.

- [MozRepl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MozRepl) (interact with Firefox from Perl via the MozRepl addon)
- [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) (use Firefox as WWW::Mechanize)
- [XUL::Gui](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XUL%3a%3aGui) (my own module that lets you build gui applications in Perl that are rendered with Firefox)

I might be able to answer more detailed questions if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Firefox is largely built using four technologies: XUL, CSS, JavaScript, and XPCOM. Extensions are also built using these four technologies.
XPCOM is a cross platform component object model, similar to Microsoft COM. It has multiple language bindings, letting the XPCOM components be used and implemented in JavaScript, Java, and Python in addition to C++.(so no perl)
To write a extension you have to comunicate with the xpcom this is not possible from perl.